# Multiple WAN to single LAN

Tags: firewall, local-area-network, sonicwall, wide-area-network

I have a block of static external IPs and I'm trying to route them to a single internal server. We have a Sonicwall TZ-210; trying to set this up results in no outbound traffic and an error warning about few(LAN) to many(WAN). I know this has to be a feature of Sonicwall to allow for redundant ISPs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, I wanted to know how your WAN interface was setup on your SonicWall Appliance (DHCP, PPPoE, Static). Second, do you have a modem on which the SonicWall is plugged in or the Internet goes directly on the WAN Interface of the SonicWall? Third, is the IP address block comes from the same ISP? If so, are you planning on having multiple server/network devices with different IP addresses? Otherwise, it is not really useful to have multiple IP addresses point to the same place that comes from the same ISP. You should use multiple IP addresses in case you have like one public mail server, one p

Answer (score 1):

This is completely supported.  See https://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/consumer/kbdetail.asp?kbid=7828

As Holytoutant mentioned, you'll need to come up with a plan for any public services, but all internal traffic can be load balanced easily.